# Android App crashing on Android version 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-activity

hi i am making a android app and uploaded on play store, i have tested many time it's working fine

But client saying is't not working on 4.1.2 , It's still crashing. 
Play store url:[URL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jobDiagnosis.free)

My manifest XML code is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jobDiagnosis.free"
    android:versionCode="34"
    android:versionName="5.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.jobDiagnosis.free.Splash"


            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity android:name=".Main_Search" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
           android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"   />
         <activity android:name=".JobSearch" android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
           android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"   />
         <activity android:name=".Job_Description" android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"      />
         <activity android:name=".Saved_jobs" android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation"    />
          <activity android:name=".MyProfile" android:label="@string/app_name"
                          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"  
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"       />
           <activity android:name=".AboutUs" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
           <activity android:name=".Selected_JobDescriptionActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"   />
           <activity android:name=".ApplyJobActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"  />
           <activity android:name="com.quantcast.measurement.service.AboutQuantcastScreen" > </activity>
             <activity android:name=".Saved_JobView" android:label="@string/app_name"    />
              <activity android:name=".Main_listview" android:label="@string/app_name"   />
              <activity android:name=".RecentlyViewd" android:label="@string/app_name"   />

                 <activity android:name=".Tab_Bar" android:label="@string/app_name"  />

                   <activity android:name=".ActivityStack" android:label="@string/app_name"  />

                    <activity android:name=".JobAlert" android:label="@string/app_name" />
                      <activity android:name=".Notify" android:label="@string/app_name" 
                          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"  />

                        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Play store Crash Code

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 66: http://www.jobdiagnosis.com/fjobsrchservise_alert.php?keyword=Food / Bev /Hosp&location=27534&myid=nullstart=0&aff_id=anapp
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
at com.jobDiagnosis.free.Notify$NotifyAsync.doInBackground(Notify.java:485)
at com.jobDiagnosis.free.Notify$NotifyAsync.doInBackground(Notify.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 5 more
```

2

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 66: http://www.jobdiagnosis.com/fjobsrchservise_alert.php?keyword=Food / Bev /Hosp&location=27534&myid=null&start=0&aff_id=anapp
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
at com.jobDiagnosis.free.JobAlert$SearchAsync.doInBackground(JobAlert.java:724)
at com.jobDiagnosis.free.JobAlert$SearchAsync.doInBackground(JobAlert.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 5 more
```

Please suggest me how i can fix this problem

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you doing parsing or calling webservices ? in that task

Comment: yes i am using xml response  web service and calling on Async class

Comment: can you post your logcat when the app crashes? If the app crashes on a device that downloaded your app from the playstore, it should be on the developer console

Comment: You need to do it in AsyncTask.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot Yes I am calling web service in AsyncTask

Comment: can you post your logcat when the app crashes. then only we can under stand the issue.

Comment: post your doInBackground code

Comment: not crashing our hand , crashing occur only for client side then i don't have log cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to URL-encode the parameters in your URL. The `keyword` parameter contains space characters. These characters are not allowed in URLs. Also, it looks like you are missing an "&" character between the `myid` parameter and the `start` parameter. See this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 66: http://www.jobdiagnosis.com/fjobsrchservise_alert.php?keyword=Food / Bev /Hosp&location=27534&myid=nullstart=0&aff_id=anapp
```